# Rewriting a core function?

Tags: core

As I understand it, it's possible to overwrite core functions in wordpress, without touching the core itself, which is of obvious benefit.

Now, certain functions are 'pluggable', but not all of them.

I'm trying to overwrite the function that outputs the featured image thumbnail in the admin panel to be a custom size, it's not really difficult to do this in the core. The problem arises when I try to put it in my functions.php as a renamed function.

This is the core function, edited. What I'd do is just rename it and put it in functions.php, but then how do I actually have it overwrite the 'core' function itself?

```
function _wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id = null, $post = null ) {
    global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $post = get_post( $post );

    $upload_iframe_src = esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src('image', $post->ID ) );
    $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="' . esc_attr__( 'Set featured image' ) . '" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">%s</a></p>';
    $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, esc_html__( 'Set featured image' ) );

    if ( $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        $old_content_width = $content_width;
        $content_width = 700;
        if ( !isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post-thumbnail'] ) )
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
        else
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
        if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, $thumbnail_html );
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
        }
        $content_width = $old_content_width;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID );
}
```

Comment: The easiest hack would be to copy that function in your `functions.php`, rename it, modify as needed, and then use it instead.

Comment: I done that, when I rename it and put it in functions.php it doesn't override the core function.

Comment: It will not override, it will just be a "new" function that you can use instead of `_wp_post_thumbnail_html`.

Comment: And how would I go about using the new function instead of _wp_post_thumbnail_html? Sorry if that's a silly question.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. if you're calling the function yourself, you can call the new function. Else you can write a function to filter the output using the `admin_post_thumbnail_html` filter.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to override a core function for that, what you need to do is to hook on the `admin_post_thumbnail_html` filter.

```
add_filter('admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse107096_wp_post_thumbnail_html',10, 2);

function wpse107096_wp_post_thumbnail_html( $thumbnail_id = null, $post = null ) {
    global $content_width, $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $post = get_post( $post );

    $upload_iframe_src = esc_url( get_upload_iframe_src('image', $post->ID ) );
    $set_thumbnail_link = '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a title="' . esc_attr__( 'Set featured image' ) . '" href="%s" id="set-post-thumbnail" class="thickbox">%s</a></p>';
    $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, esc_html__( 'Set featured image' ) );

    if ( $thumbnail_id && get_post( $thumbnail_id ) ) {
        $old_content_width = $content_width;
        $content_width = 700;
        if ( !isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes['post-thumbnail'] ) )
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array( $content_width, $content_width ) );
        else
            $thumbnail_html = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, 'post-thumbnail' );
        if ( !empty( $thumbnail_html ) ) {
            $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'set_post_thumbnail-' . $post->ID );
            $content = sprintf( $set_thumbnail_link, $upload_iframe_src, $thumbnail_html );
            $content .= '<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#" id="remove-post-thumbnail" onclick="WPRemoveThumbnail(\'' . $ajax_nonce . '\');return false;">' . esc_html__( 'Remove featured image' ) . '</a></p>';
        }
        $content_width = $old_content_width;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

yes, you will waste some CPU cycles because of the repeated computation, but that is the proper way to do it. If it bothers you then you should look for a smarter way to set the proper required content size.

Comment: This fails to display the thumbnail for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Only [the functions defined as "pluggable" functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) can be overridden in a plugin/theme.

But... You shouldn't need to rewrite a core function to resize your featured images.  See instead [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) (and, more generally, [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)).

Comment: Resize featured images IN the admin panel, not on the front end of the site, which is easy.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to resize in the Admin panel?  The thumbnail of the image that is displayed?  Or are you looking to have control over how large the Featured Image is once it's attached to a post/page?

Comment: Yes, the thumbnail image that's displayed in the admin panel. So far I can't seem to get the filter to work properly so the only way is to over write the core function.

Comment: What filter(s) have you tried?  You can check on the full list of filters at sites like http://wpseek.com/ or http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/ -- they're not all listed in the Codex, not by a long shot.

Comment: Only admin_post_thumbnail_html as per mark's answer, I have no idea which other ones to even try.