# Get URL of current featured image with JS in edit post view

Tags: wp-admin, post-thumbnails, javascript, media-modal

Is it possible, somehow, to fetch the URL of the currently set featured image when you're in the edit post view?

So far I've looked at fetching via jQuery such as:

```
var url = jQuery('#set-post-thumbnail img').attr('src');
```

Which works, but I need the full sized image rather than the thumbnail. So it's no good.

My second approach was to open the modal programmatically, then I was able to fetch the URL. But this approach is no good either, as it's very disruptive to the user (the code is triggered via a radio button change).

```
featuredImage = wp.media.featuredImage.frame();
featuredImage.open();
var attachment = featuredImage.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
// url is now available in attachment.url
```

I guess my last resort would be to fetch the ID of the image and then use Ajax to send a request to figure out the URL, but that feels a very slow and cumbersome solution to a problem like this.

Anyone with a good suggestion?

Comment: In what context? Your efforts are focused on Javascript but it isn't clear that you need it to be Javascript or if that is just what you've been trying. It is very easy to get the featured image in PHP, for example. Even if you do need Javascript functionality it may be easier to use PHP to print a Javascript variable to the page.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Ah, yeah, maybe I was unclear. Purpose was to be able to run another script (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) on the featured image in the backend and then be able to save those values. In the end I was able to solve it by repurposing the featured image metabox logic to output an additional "data-full" tag (with the full sized image) with the featured image thumbnail. I could then snag that URL with jQuery easily.

Comment: That sounds like an overly complicated solution, and possibly a Core hack?

Comment: Perhaps complicated. But it was the solution I went with.. Something in the lines of this answer (don't have access to the code base atm): http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107108/2830